# On click of a row in a dynamically generated table, get its radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my webpage, I have a button whose click dynamically generates a table. Each row of the table has a radio button. Now, I am trying to get the corresponding radio button of a row checked when I click on that row. 
Here's the HTML

```
Insert table here
<button name="myreq" id="myreq" class="homeButtons">My Requests</button>
<table class="newreqtable" id="myrequesttable"></table>
```

Here's the JS for what I'm trying to achieve. I have added values in the 'jsarray' manually for ease in the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4MYGa/1/

```
$("#myreq")
.button()
.click(function () {

var jsarray = new Array();
jsarray.push("1");
jsarray.push("requestor1");
jsarray.push("approver1");
jsarray.push("pending");
jsarray.push("chrome");
jsarray.push("25");
jsarray.push("source1");
jsarray.push("dest1");
jsarray.push("2");
jsarray.push("requestor2");
jsarray.push("approver2");
jsarray.push("pending");
jsarray.push("firefox");
jsarray.push("25");
jsarray.push("source2");
jsarray.push("dest2");

var table = '<table>';
table += '<tr><th>Select</th><th>RequestID</th><th >Requester</th><th>Approver</th><th>Status</th><th>Product</th><th>Version</th><th>Source</th><th>Destination</th></tr>';

for (var j = 0; j < jsarray.length; j += 8) {
    table += '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="requestradio" id="rad' + j + '"></td><td>' + jsarray[j] + '</td><td>' + jsarray[j + 1] + '</td><td>' + jsarray[j + 2] + '</td><td>' + jsarray[j + 3] + '</td><td>' + jsarray[j + 4] + '</td><td>' + jsarray[j + 5] + '</td><td>' + jsarray[j + 6] + '</td><td>' + jsarray[j + 7] + '</td></tr>';
}
table += '</table>';
$("#myrequesttable").html(table);
});

$('#myrequesttable tr').click(function () {

$('#myrequesttable tr').removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).find('[name="requestradio"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the event when dom is ready.

```
 $("#myrequesttable").html(table);
//bind event when dom is ready
$('#myrequesttable tr').click(function () {
$('#myrequesttable tr').removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).find('[name="requestradio"]').prop('checked', true);
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MYGa/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('body').on('click','#myrequesttable tr',function (){

    $('#myrequesttable tr').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).find('[name="requestradio"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4MYGa/5/)

Answer (score 1):

change your click event:

```
$('#myrequesttable tr').click(function () {
```

to this:

```
$('#myrequesttable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MYGa/7/)

See your all the `<tr/>s` are dynamically generated so they don't exist when the page was loaded, solution to this issue is to delegate the event to the closest static parent in your page dom, which is `#myrequesttable` table. so you have to delegate to this.

Although you can delegate to `$(document)` itself but if performance is concerned then it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code to be the following:

```
// Cache $("#myrequesttable")
var $myrequesttable = $("#myrequesttable");
$myrequesttable
    .on("click", "tr", function () {
        // Cache $(this)
        var $this = $(this);
        $myrequesttable.find("tr").removeClass("active");
        $this.addClass("active");
        $this.find('input:radio[name="requestradio"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
```